# Is there a reason why the number of channels/filters and batch sizes in many deep learning models are in powers of 2?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, caffe

In many models the number of channels is kept in powers of 2. Also the batch-sizes are described in powers of 2. Is there any reason behind this design choice?

Comment: see this quora answer https://www.quora.com/Should-I-use-powers-of-2-when-choosing-the-size-of-a-batch-size-when-training-my-Neural-Network

Answer (score 1):

There is no significant in keeping channels and batch size as powers of 2.  You can keep any number you want.

Comment: we simply like round numbers ;)

Answer (score 0):

> In many models the number of channels is kept in powers of 2. Also the batch-sizes are described in powers of 2. Is there any reason behind this design choice?

While both could probably be optimized for speed (cache-alignment? optimal usage of CUDA cores?) to be powers of two, I am 95% certain that 99.9% do it because others used the same numbers / it worked.

For both hyperparameters you could choose any positive integer. So what would you try? Keep in mind, each complete evaluation takes at least several hours. Hence I guess if people play with this parameter, they make something like a binary search: Starting from one number, doubling keep doubling if it improves until an upper bound is found. At some point the differences are minor and then it is irrelevant what you choose. And people will wonder less if you write that you used a batch size of 64 than if you write that you used 50. Or 42.